# Building a tree "backwards"

Tags: python

I need to create a tree-like structure in Python. I have a function get(parentId), which returns a list of objects with that parent -- I think that should be done recursively.

The result should be something like this: `["root object", ["child1 of root", "child2 of root", ["child2-1", "child2-2"]]]`

Every object has a attribute parent, which is is the parentId for get(), but as a starting point I only have the root object.

Comment: How this can be done. I'm mentally stuck here, but I need to get this done asap... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are still interested in a list representation of the tree (which is not necessarily a useless thing to do), this is a recursive function definition that I believe does what you need (provided that the `get()` function has indeed been defined before):

```
def build_tree(node):
    return [node,[build_tree(child) for child in get(node)]]
```

You could use it in a way similar to this:

```
root = 1  # or whatever other representation you may use for root
list = build_tree(root)
print list
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard data structure for a tree, and it's not a list of lists.

Make a class `Node`, with an attribute `children` containing a `list` (or `set`, if you don't care about the order) of "child" nodes. Also make a method `add_child` which takes a node, sets that node's `parent`, and adds it to the `children` list. Something like:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, children={}):
        self.parent = None
        self.children = children

    def add_child(self, child):
        child.parent = self
        self.children.add(child)
```

To walk the tree, just ask for the root's children, then their children, etc. This can be done recursively, though for speed and memory efficiency you probably want to do it iteratively in Python.

```
def walk(root):
    yield root
    for child in root.children:
        for elt in walk(child):
            yield elt
```

---

Of course, this has been done many many times before, so you shouldn't write it yourself unless it's homework or a learning exercise.

Since HTML/XML documents are structured like trees, you should probably use one of the many DOM tree libraries for the actual data structure. Try `xml.dom.minidom` or `lxml`.

Comment: I can't use "other" structures, because both the data source (get()) and the target (list of list of...) is defined :(

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I misunderstood the question.